# File caching and file permission

Tags: android, android-file, android-permissions, image-caching

I have a problem implementing caching in my app and deploying it on 4.2.x devices.

When i save a file in the app cache directory i'm unable to read it. I use a file manager with  root permissions to explore cache folder and the **files are correctly present in my cache folder but when i try to read them a get a file not found error**.

***This problem is related only to 4.2 android version. In 4.1- all works fine***

This is the code i use to write the file

```
public static void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {

        if (bmp == null)
            return;

        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            boolean res = bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        f.setReadable(true, false);
    }
```

This is how i construct the file object

```
File bitmapFile = new File(ImageManager.getInstance().getCacheDir(), key);
```

This is how get the cache path

```
if (Config.USE_INTERNAL_CACHE == false && sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        cacheDir = MyApp.getInstance().getExternalCacheDir();
    } else {
        cacheDir = MyApp.getInstance().getCacheDir();

    }
    if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }
```

At this point my file are correctly written to

```
/data/data/my.app.package/cache/
```

This is the code i use to read the files

```
public BitmapDrawable readFile(String fileName) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(getCacheDir()+"/"+fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    if (bmp == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new BitmapDrawable(MyApp.getInstance().getResources(), bmp);
}
```

This always generate this error:

```
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/my.app.package/cache/File Name: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init(FileInputStream.java:105)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    atmy.app.package.instanceManager.ImageManager.readFile(ImageManager.java:246)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    atmy.app.package.instanceManager.ImageManager$ImageQueueManager.run(ImageManager.java:186)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    atlibcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
01-22 11:23:47.158: W/System.err(20660):    ... 5 more
```

related to this line:

```
in = new FileInputStream(getCacheDir()+"/"+fileName);
```

I have already added this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The path and the name file related to this error are correct and the file exists in the cache folder, so why i cannot read them? **I think it could be an user permission related issue due to the new multiuser features introduced in android 4.2 but i cant figure it out. **I also try to set the file `.setReadable(true, false)` but nothing. Thanks